# How we can pass data from one view to another in ASP.NET mvc framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a page(view) and on submit i transfer control to another page(view) and i want some values which was filled in first view to transfer to next. How we can achieve that in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can all conventional data transfer method which are available in ASP.net

Client Side:
1. Cookie
2. Querystring

Server side:
1. Sessions

For more information on these see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

Thanks,
Ashwani